# Django apache wsgi returns Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, ssh, apache2, mod-wsgi, basic-authentication

I want to have a base authentication into my django application by apache's base auth.

my config looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName url.test.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    WSGIDaemonProcess projectname \
        python-home=/home/user/app/project/env \
        python-path=/home/user/app/project:/home/user/app/project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
    WSGIProcessGroup projectname
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/app/project/app/server/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    Alias /static/ /home/user/app/app/project/static/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-log combined
    LogLevel info

    # Protecting with basic authentication
    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require user testuser
        AuthBasicProvider wsgi
        WSGIAuthUserScript /home/user/app/project/app/server/wsgi.py
    </Location>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/project.app.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/project.app.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

and wsgi.py containing:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/app/project')
sys.path.append('/home/user/app/project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages')

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.app.settings"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

with this setup I get the error message:

> AH01618: user testuser not found: /

after some research I've seen that I probably should remove `AuthBasicProvider` and `WSGIAuthUserScript` from `Location` to:

```
# Protecting with basic authentication
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require user testuser
</Location>
```

this leads to the password being accepted, but then I get a 403 error in the django application:

> Forbidden: /
>
> [11/Mar/2020 17:23:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 13

as I'm usually more on the coding side I'm not super familiar with the setup of the django application behind apache and struggling. Anyone sees my problem?